# is it possible to return multiple responses to a POST using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey, response

I am designing a rest service using Jersey, Tomcat and JDK11.
I don't know if I can receive a JSON with multiples instances of an object and be able to return a response to every single instance.
Basically, the server receives a POST request, the JSON (from the request) has the instances A, B, C, D. I have in my database the instances B and C. So I should return the responses A-> OK, B-> NOT ACCEPTABLE, C-> NOT ACCEPTABLE,  D -> OK

What is the correct approach in my case?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds like you should maybe iterate over each JSON object in the POST body and do the logic to check if its in the database etc and return an OK or NOT ACCEPTABLE. 

Then collect the results from your iteration and build a custom Response class which can return a status of 200 and a custom message with your required output

Comment: One request gets one response. You can send list of JSON response objects as a response. It's basically up to you how you want to structure it. There is no correct answer. Any answer will just be someones opinion. Hence I am voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: It's a little bit late but I ended creating a new class which contains the code, the meaning and a message. I return a 200 response with a JSON array which contains the true responses to every instance. Thank you for the help.